# how to fix the game script to be compatible on LOVE2D 0.9+

Tags: porting, love2d

interested this awesome platform, likely could make a game prototype in very short time period. obtained a few game scripts in .love format from the web, however they were made for love2d 0.8 and could not run on version 0.9+. checked the wiki, it confirmed 0.9+ broke the compatibility to 0.8 script, a nos of functions were replaced or depreciated.

any script which could convert the old .love (or scripts) to 0.9+ compatible?

or any conversion table that i could fix the old script manually to be compatible with 0.9+,

in wiki there is a long list of changes but not comprehensive to make the conversion straight-forward.

i am running love 0.9.1 on lubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier said than done, but here's a very simple example:

```
if love.filesystem then
    love.filesystem.mkdir = love.filesystem.createDirectory
    love.filesystem.enumerate = love.filesystem.getDirectoryItems
end
if love.graphics then
    love.graphics.drawq = love.graphics.draw
    love.graphics.quad = love.graphics.polygon
    love.graphics.triangle = love.graphics.polygon
end
if love.graphics and love.window then
    love.graphics.setCaption = love.window.setTitle
end
```

And so on.